# How to insert null manually in MyBatis Insert Query

Tags: mybatis

This is from a popular example.

```
    <!-- Insert example, using the Account parameter class -->
<insert id="insertAccount" parameterType="Account">
  insert into ACCOUNT (
ACC_ID,
ACC_FIRST_NAME,
ACC_LAST_NAME,
ACC_EMAIL
)values (
    #{id}, #{firstName}, #{lastName}, #{emailAddress}
```

)

I want to insert null for one of the field manually.

```
   <!-- Insert example, using the Account parameter class -->
<insert id="insertAccount" parameterType="Account">
  insert into ACCOUNT (
ACC_ID,
ACC_FIRST_NAME,
ACC_LAST_NAME,
ACC_EMAIL
)values (
    #{id}, #{firstName}, #{lastName}, #{null}
```

)

But I am getting this exception

```
   org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'null'
```

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyBatis uses #{propertyName} to define a property. If you use the name 'NULL' it ever looks for getNull() and setNull(...) or named parameter or map. However if the value is ever null in your case, you can omit the value, just if you have no default value for that column in the database.

```
<insert id="insertAccount" parameterType="Account">
  insert into ACCOUNT (
ACC_ID,
ACC_FIRST_NAME,
ACC_LAST_NAME
)values (
    #{id}, #{firstName}, #{lastName}
);
```

Or enter the exact value the same way as in an SQL command:

```
<insert id="insertAccount" parameterType="Account">
  insert into ACCOUNT (
ACC_ID,
ACC_FIRST_NAME,
ACC_LAST_NAME,
ACC_EMAIL
)values (
    #{id}, #{firstName}, #{lastName}, null
);
```

Comment: thanks...bye the way,I was confused by the new syntax of MyBatis.

Comment: What if you want to dynamically determine if it's null or not?
I mean suppose the fouth parameter was the age. So I 'd like to write #{age} instead of #{null} and whenever I pass a non null parameter a value is inserted and when the age I pass as a parameter is null then NULL is inserted. 
How 'd you do this?, right now I 'm trying it but a jdbc exception (Invalida type for column) is thrown. [using Oracle]

Comment: @Nicolas Barrera myBatis has also condition tags supporting dynamic SQL. Probably ask your own new question containing full SQL/myBatis snippet.

Comment: @NicolasBarrera... I have exact same doubt ? Did you post the question any where ?